# How to use "Add link" pop up for a WordPress widget

Tags: posts, links, api, wysiwyg, html-editor

In the WYSIWYG editor of WordPress you get pop up if you want to add a link for a text. Is there a possibility to access this functionality? Because I want to use this pop up for a WordPress widget that I created so that you can add links to a widget if you configure it in the backend.

Here is a screenshot of what I mean:
[image]

Answer (score 8):

I tried for a bit and could not get this to work perfectly, but it's close, it's hard to extend with the `<form>` for the popup styles being hardcoded, thought possible with more work.

*To get started you can:*

Enqueue the link popup javascript and styles, the main .js file is `wp-includes/wplink.js`. Depending on where you loading this you might need to add more or less scripts/styles since it relies on several (*thickbox, jQuery-ui, ui-dialog, etc*).

```
wp_enqueue_script('wplink');
wp_enqueue_script('wpdialogs-popup'); //also might need this

// need these styles
wp_enqueue_style('wp-jquery-ui-dialog');
wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
```

Set the translatable variable:

```
var wpLinkL10n = {"title":"Insert\/edit link","update":"Update","save":"Add Link","noTitle":"(no title)","noMatchesFound":"No matches found."};
```

Now you *should* be able to extend the `wpLink` function using something like:

```
// test button
<button class="link-btn">Click button for Links</button>

jQuery('.link-btn').on('click', function(event) {
  wpActiveEditor = true;
  wpLink.title = "Hello"; //Custom title example
  wpLink.open();    // Open the link popup
  return false;
});
```

You need a `<form>` element for the pop-up which by defualt is way to long to paste here, you can see the defualt one here: https://gist.github.com/wycks/6402573

Now there are major problems with this namely I did not add any closing or submission (or checking) javascript to the function, such as `wpLink.close` or `wpLink.textarea`, so see `wplink.js` for further info.

Sorry this just takes way to long to fiddle with, unless I am missing something basic, but that should get you most of the way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I solved the style/script references with using: <? wp_editor('', ''); ?> - So maybe I can get a shorter solution! But there is still the question on how to receive the selected link.

Comment: Thanks for posting this; it led to me finding the answer I needed. In my case I just had to explicitly enqueue the "wpdialogs" script, which wasn't working when specified as a dependency.
`wp_enqueue_script('wpdialogs');`